# need the sum of some dictionary values if present in input

Tags: python

so this is my code.
while the loop is running and I input bowl it should output 8,50. next input from loop should be added  to the last output, this loop has to continue until control+d is entered. anybody got some tips for me?
I'm pretty new to coding.
I've tried adding the output from the validated input to a new list eventually printing the sum of that list, but so far I haven't got lucky

```
def main():
    a = order()


menu = {
    "Baja Taco": 4.00,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
}


def order():
    while True:
        try:
            i = input("Input: ")
            i = i.title()             # converts letter from input to titlecase
            if i in menu:
                print("total: ${:.2f}".format(menu.get(i)))
        except (EOFError):
            print('')
            break


main()
```

Comment: Please explain your expected output, how you tried and what is your issue. The title of the post is not sufficient.

Comment: hi, sorry I didn't understand where to type my expected output. i updated the file, is it more clear now?

Comment: You can accumulate total by: 1. set to 0 before while loop ie. `total = 0`, 2. update total before print statement i.e. `total += menu[i]`, and 3)print total i.e. `print("total: ${:.2f}".format(total))`

Comment: thanks! this is the "chosen answer"! This is most understandable for me, since the other answers invoked code I did not understand fully yet but hopefully in the future I will understand that too

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, Use a flag to exit from the loop,

```
menu = {
    "Baja Taco": 4.00,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
}


def order():
    print("Please press Q/q for exit:")
    break_point = True
    total = 0
    while break_point:
        i = input("Input: ")
        key = i.title()
        if key in menu:
            total += menu.get(key)
            print("total: ${:.2f}".format(total))
        if i.lower() == 'q':
            break_point = False
```

You can use a `total` value and keep an update with the price in each loop if the item exists in the menu. Also, used a flag called `break_point` which will check with the input is `q` and exit from the while loop.

Execution:

```
Please press Q/q for exit:
Input: Taco
total: $3.00
Input: Nachos
total: $14.00
Input: q
```

Comment: This would be a better answer with the elaboration addressing the question, rather than the loop exit mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to keep a running tally of what's been ordered.

```
def order():
    orders = []
    while True:
        try:
            i = input("Input: ")
            i = i.title()             # converts letter from input to titlecase
            if i in menu:
                orders.append((i, menu[i]))
        except EOFError:
            break

    # Now you can print out the tuples or sum their second elements.
```

If you input:

```
Input: Baja Taco
Input: Bowl
```

`orders` would be:

```
[('Baja Taco', 4.00), ('Bowl', 8.50)]
```

From which point it's straightforward to calculate a sum or print info about each order.